# What is the meaning of 'divalicious'?

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

I have been reading an article with the following line:

> Now what happened next was such a **divalicious** move

My question is about the word "divalicious".

I have looked it up in two dictionaries but such word is not exist at all.

What is its meaning?

Comment: Since it's an entirely made up one-off usage, it's really just a matter of opinion what it means. [In context](http://scoopempire.com/hesham-mansour-is-all-of-us/) it seems to be about someone who might be described as a "diva", so that's probably the only justification for switching ***delicious*** to ***divalicious***.

Comment: ***-licious***: (*combining form*) (*informal*) forming adjectives denoting someone or something as delightful or extremely attractive. Example: "babelicious" (https://www.google.com/#q=define+-licious)

Comment: It's a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "diva" and "delicious".

Answer (score 2):

**divalicious move**

http://www.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2014916/rs_500x282-141016115143-insta.gif

The link above shows a pre-teen boy performing a delicious *move* / *body movement*, typical of a "diva" from the world of pop or showbusiness.

*Divalicious* is an example of a **[blend word](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/blendterm.htm)**, ***diva*** is joined to ***delicious***, minus the prefix **de-**.

> A **blend** is a word formed by merging the sounds and meanings of two or more other words or word parts. Also known as a *portmanteau word*, *telescoping*, *lexical interlocking*, and *semantic conflation*.
>
> - affluenza (affluent + influenza)
> - agitprop (agitation + propaganda)
> - alcopop (alcohol + pop)
> - bash (bat + mash)
> - biopic (biography + picture)
> - Breathalyzer (breath + analyzer)
> - camcorder (camera + recorder)
> - chexting (cheating + texting)
> - cosmeceutical (cosmetic + pharmaceutical)